# How long would it take to travel from the United Kingdom to America in 1890?

Tags: travel

For a short story I plan to write, I was wondering how long it would take individuals to travel from the United Kingdom to America in 1890.

Comment: @BCLC That question is about mail delivery times; this one is about passenger travel times. Very similar, but I'm inclined to say not a duplicate.

Comment: @Semaphore Fine. Before, one of my questions was closed or marked as duplicate I think due to similarity. As I recall, I had to combine some of my questions. Is this or is this not common practice in SE?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It took between 7 and 10 days, depending on the ship and the weather. The ships sailed out of Liverpool and Queenstown. Here is a notice from **"London and Its Environs: Handbook for Travellers" (1889)**:

[image]

Comment: "sailed" is a misnomer in this case, as it's impossible to make this trip this quickly without steam power.

Comment: @congusbongus Obviously you don't do much cruising, otherwise you would know that "sail" is the standard term even today. Go to http://www.carnival.com/ (carnival cruise lines) or any cruise ship web page. Says "sail" right on the front page.

Comment: @congusbongus you'd be surprised at the speed of ships like clippers and some schooners.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It will really help me.

Answer (score 12):

It turns out there was an [unofficial award](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Riband) for doing this particular trip the quickest in a passenger liner, so we have pretty good records. Of course a typical passage would be a bit slower than one where a captain was pushing to win the record, but the times can be seen as a close lower bound to how long it would take for a typical trip.

In the 1890's the Blue Riband was [held by double-screw steamships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Riband#Double_screw_steamers_.281889.E2.80.931907.29). A four-time holder was the [SS Majestic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS_Majestic_(1889)), which made her maiden voyage in 1890 from Liverpool to New York in a bit less than six and a half days. That wasn't quite good enough for the record. At the time the [City of Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS_City_of_Paris_(1888)) held the record on a run the same direction between those two cities at a bit under 6 days. (The prize was for average speed in knots, so it doesn't translate perfectly to clock time, but there is a relationship).

Now of course if you weren't paying top dollar on a state-of-the-art cruise liner it would probably be considerably slower, but this should give you a ballpark figure and a good idea of the lower bound for a crossing.

Comment: Interestingly, when I saw the [musical Titanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanic_(musical)), attempting to win the Blue Riband was put forth as one of the factors that contributed to her demise.

Comment: I think this is a known historical fact. No reference to a musical is necessary.

Comment: @Alex - I'll agree that for a theory that's out there, there should be a better reference available.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was very interesting to read about this unofficial award.